# How to open a tmux session dynamically?

Tags: shell, tmux, xargs

I am trying to open an active session dynamically from the Terminal but I keep getting this:

> can't find session stuff

Here's what I'm doing, really simple stuff:

```
$ echo stuff | xargs -0 tmux a -t
```

And if I list the sessions, `stuff` is there as you can see:

```
$ tmux ls
stuff: 1 windows (created Wed Mar 23 21:20:55 2016) [191x35]
work: 3 windows (created Tue Mar 22 16:10:50 2016) [191x35]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
tmux attach -t "$(echo stuff)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending NUL-delimited data to `xargs` so it is including the newline from `echo` in the name.

Drop `-0` from the `xargs` command line or use `printf 'stuff\0'` instead of the `echo`.

Comment: Well, by dropping `-0` from `xargs` now I get the following: `open terminal failed: not a terminal`

Comment: Possibly because you are running under `xargs`. Try Kent's solution? What's the *actual* scenario here? What sort of "dynamic" session name are you dealing with?